# What causes the offset of the cube here?

Tags: transforms

Can anyone tell me, what causes the offset of the cube in this scene?
There is a parent object (the grid) at 0,0,0 and its child object (the cube) at (0,0,0) local coordinates. It has no delta transform. I can't find, what causes the shift. Is it a bug or I don't know anything?
[image]

[Here is the .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ntO_P6p5qNfuxqmnnoyL8Nr3hiXn7VCw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you should definitely not force us to ask for access if you want to help from us...sorry

Comment: Oh, sorry! It was my mistake. I changed the link permission, now you can download it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you've parented an object, its location will stay the one it had before parenting. If your cube was at the center of the scene (location 0:0:0), you've parented it and moved the parent, it's normal that the cube still located at 0:0:0 even though it is no longer visually at the center of the scene.

Comment: If both the child and the parent are at local coordinates 0,0,0, there is no reason for the child to be displaced. Where does this offset value appear numerically in the editor?

Comment: it doesn't appear, the location remains 0:0:0, maybe describe what you exactly did to have your current scene?

Comment: To be honest, I can't remember. I exprerimented with coordinate tranformations, Geom Nodes and parenting, and this happened, but I don't know yet exactly, how to reproduce this.